# Help with determining power dissipation of resistor in parallel

Tags: voltage, resistance, parallel, power-dissipation

I've been struggling with this question for a while for some reason, even though it seems much easier that it should be. The question asks for the power dissipated in resistor R (the one in the middle) in terms of R and V. So far I have found the total resistance of the circuit and the current running through the whole circuit, however I am unsure of what to do now. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Associated diagram]

Comment: Well, calculate the potentials between the 2 voltage dividers as wel the total voltage divider  of the 4 resistors on the outside, than you can extract the amount of current that goes through "R". you can combine the lower "3R" and "R2" to form a single resistor in parallel with "R" than this new resistor can be combined with R to again a new resistor, leaving your with 3 resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total equivalent resistance and total current are,

$$ R_{total} = 2R + \frac{5R \times R}{5R + R} + 3R = \frac{35}{6}R $$
$$ I_{total} = \frac{V}{\frac{35}{6}R} = \frac{6V}{35R} $$

Voltage drop on the middle resistor,

$$ V_R = I_{total} \times \frac{5R}{6} = \frac{V}{7} $$

Power consumption on the middle resistor,

$$ P_R = \frac{V_R^2}{R} = \frac{V^2}{49R} $$

Refer the following equivalent circuit.
[image]

Comment: Please don't give out complete solutions to homework questions. We prefer to see the OP demonstrate a substantial effort to answer the question themselves, then only give hints and suggestions so they can find the answer themselves.